# How i can upload products data on Amazon using web service

Tags: xml, c#-4.0, amazon-mws

My requirement is to upload product's data on amazon using API or something else(with xml) without using any dll because i would like to do code with different language.

Anyone knows about how i can achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean that you don't want to use the Amazon-provided C# client library for MWS, then, sure, you can re-implement a similar client library in any language you want. The Amazon clients are available in C#, Java and PHP, but the API itself is documented independently of programming languages (see [here](https://developer.amazonservices.com/).